# How to correct scattered pagination links and objects view in browser while using pagination() function in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on **Laravel 8** framework, PHP 8 and MariaDB 10.4.17.

I am using `paginate()` feature in controller class and `{{$variable->links()}}` in .blade.php view file.

When testing the outcome on the browser, **I am getting the paginator links and objects scattered**.

Here is how I use `paginate()` in controller class :

```
class Homepage extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $data['articles']=Article::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(1);

        return view('front.homepage',$data);

    }
```

Here is how I call pagination in my .blade.php view file :

```
{{$articles->links()}}
```

Finally, this is the scattered view I get in browser:

[image: browser snapshot]

I would be happy to hear from you, if you have any idea why such untidiness occurs and how to correct it?

Comment: That looks like you’re missing some proper _formatting_ of the output on the client side … The `<` and `>` are probably SVG icons or something like that here, I’m guessing? Then you might need to format those to an appropriate size.

Comment: Hello, I have 3 kinds of css links..: Bootstrap core CSS, Custom fonts, Custom styles, Where would you think I should do the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, I am using Bootstrap and Laravel 8 is using TailwindCss pagination by default. Therefore adding this:

```
 use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

to the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider class` solves the problem.

Comment: Great fix, also this `$data['articles']=Article::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(1);` can be shorten to this `$data['articles']=Article::latest()->paginate(1);`